# Which statistical test should I use, t-test or another one?

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, chemometrics

I want to compare two samples. Each of them was dried by two different methods, and I studied their physicochemical characteristics (pH, titratable acidity, total sugars, etc.) to see the influence of the drying methods on physicochemical properties.

I conducted three tests for each sample for the different physicochemical parameters. Which test should I use to look for statistically significant differences?

This is an example of my work:

[image]

Comment: Intuitively, just looking a your pH measurements, it seems that Sample 1 has pH $\approx 4.35$ and Sample 2 has pH $\approx 4.04,$ with very little variation. A formal two-sample test would be appropriate. With only 3 pH observations on each Sample, a Wilcoxon signed rank test does not have the power to distinguish between the two samples. A Welch two-sample t test assumes pH measurements are normal and finds a significant difference with a very small P-value. // We would have to know more about your study (and detailed objectives) to recommend an overall statistical analysis.

Comment: In undergraduate quantitative analysis chemistry courses, this is a nominal paired t test. But the means for the two samples are so different, relative to the standard deviations, that no statistical test is necessary: sample 1 is clearly not the same as sample 2. I suggest looking at J.N. Miller and J.C. Miller, *Statistics and Chemometrics for Analytical Chemistry*, any of the 6 editions. For the 6th edition, see pages 43-45. Or any of the excellent quant books by Dan Harris. In the 7th edition of *Quantitative Chemical Analysis*, the paired t test is discussed on p. 62. Hope this helps!

Comment: Bruce ET my objective is to study the influence of drying methods on physicochemicals propreties of the fruit, and comparing betwenn two methods

Comment: the sample 1 was dried with air drying for 1 month and the sample 2 was dehydrated at 40°C for 24 h in ventilated oven